# LINQ to SQL Association to a table with 'magic values' (ie: certain values which dont exist in the related table)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq

We are migrating a Microsoft Access application that has an SQL Server Back End to VB.NET for the frontend, and using LINQ to SQL.  Most of the tables do not have a foreign key relationship on the database level, and the relationships are handled in code.  Most of this works fine, but I am having trouble with times when the value to go into the foreign key doesn't actually exist.

In the small sample data set I created below to illustrate my problem, the Orders table is related to the Suppliers table through the SupplierID field in the Orders Table.  I created a OneToMany association with the Suppliers as the Parent, and the Orders as the Child.  This gives me a Supplier.Orders list, and an Order.Supplier property which is GREAT!

In my records the SupplierID in the Orders would be SupplierID from the Suppliers table, but there are a few 'magic values'.  In this example 0 = No Supplier Exists, and -1 = TBD.

Any suggestions on how to best handle this?

I've handled this a few ways in the code so far, and none of them seem to be great:

1. I can manually set the Order.SupplierID property to 0 or -1, but I can only do that if I haven't already touched the Order.Supplier property.  If I've already done something that makes LINQ use that association, it throws a foreign key error if I try to set the ID to something that doesn't exist.
2. I can set the value bypassing the LINQ by making an SQL statement(ie: dc.Connection.CreateCommand) but now I'm no longer working within the LINQ layer
3. I could make those 'magic IDs' actually exist, but from an architecture standpoint that feels wrong, since 'No Supplier' and 'TBD' are not actually suppliers.  I would then also need to adjust anywhere that I show a list of the real Suppliers to not show those items.

[image]

I'm having trouble articulating my question well, so I apologize in advance.

This isn't the actual table structure/situation I'm dealing with, but I think it was a simpler way to demonstrate.

Comment: I would probably just set both to `null`. Always enforce foreign-keys at the database level, unless you have a very strong reason not to

Comment: I've kinda struggled with understanding your question and had to re-read it multiple times.  To me this really does smell of very poor DB design/implementation.  Tables are either related or not.  If they are related implement the FK relationships at the DB level, even if they are optional relationships.  SQLServer is after all a RDBMS (R for relational).  If you're not going to do that, save yourself the overheads of SQL server and use flat files

Comment: @Hursey technical detail: The "R" in "relational" doesn't refer to foreign key relationships between tables. "Relational" means "there are certain data elements which are all related to each other because they are all functionally dependent upon the same key, and so we put those elements together into something called a [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(database)) (a table, in a sql database)".

Comment: LINQ-to-SQL, really?